# SymFromAddr result is false in Release environment

Tags: c++, c, callstack, debug-symbols

pdb file exists and works normally in Debug mode, but the problem occurs only in the Release version.

It is a function that prints the call stack. How can I solve it?

One of the strange things when debugging was that the address was different in Relese version and Debug mode.

```
std::string SymbolLookup::GetSymbolString(void* address) const{
    if (address == nullptr) 
    {
        return "";
    }

    DWORD displacement = 0;
    DWORD addr = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(address);
    SymbolBuffer symbol;
    char buffer[kStrBufferSize] = { 0, };
    
    IMAGEHLP_LINE line;
    line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE);

    SymFromAddr(handle_, addr, 0, &symbol);
    DWORD Temp = GetLastError();

    BOOL ret = SymGetLineFromAddr(handle_, addr, &displacement, &line);
    if (ret) 
    {
        sprintf_s(buffer, kStrBufferSize, "%s(%d) : %s",
            line.FileName, line.LineNumber, symbol.Name);
    }
    else 
    {
        sprintf_s(buffer, kStrBufferSize, "No line info : %s", symbol.Name);
    }

    return std::string(buffer);
}

void log_callstack()
{
    SymbolLookup lookup;

    CallStack stack; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < stack.GetCount(); ++i) 
    {
        const string& str = lookup.GetSymbolString(stack[i]);
        print_log(str.c_str());
    }
}

class SymbolLookup
{
public:
    SymbolLookup() : handle_(GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        SymInitialize(handle_, nullptr, TRUE);
        SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);
    }

    std::string GetSymbolString(void* address) const;

private:
    const static size_t kStrBufferSize = 1024U;

private:
    HANDLE handle_;
};

class CallStack
{
public:
    static const size_t kMaxStackDepth = 24U;

public:
    CallStack()
    {
        count_ = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, kMaxStackDepth, addresses_, &hash_);
    }

    void* operator[] (const size_t index) const { return addresses_[index]; }

    ULONG GetHash() const { return hash_; }
    size_t GetCount() const { return count_; }

private:
    void* addresses_[kMaxStackDepth];
    ULONG hash_;
    size_t count_;
};
```

I found that the addresses value obtained through CaptureStackBackTrace is different when run with f5 and when run with Relese executable.

GetLastError() value is 487

Comment: Have you enabled debug symbols in your release build? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. With the little amount of detail, it's impossible to answer. Please also read the descriptions of the tags that you applied!

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I have activated it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes I will read it.

Comment: Have you called SymInitialize? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I also added code to call SymInitialize.

Comment: Adding some error handling and checking that all your function calls succeed is probably a good place to start

Comment: @AlanBirtles 
All functions were called normally, but only SymFromAddr failed.
The error code is 487.